# clientidmode static is not working with updatepanel which forces full postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

I have RadioButtonList & Listvie in my page. I am using update panel to avoid postback Now my radioButtonList works as filter for listview. My Problem is in my radiobuttonList I have to use clientIDmode=static but if I do that then my updatepanel has no use since there is full postback when radiobuttonList gets changed. How to solve this problem without removing clientIdmode=static. I seen some solution for kind of same post but really didn't understand. Please help me.

My code has following structure.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="areasList" CssClass="mark" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" RepeatLayout="Flow">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
ListviewHere
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Just curious: why do you "have to use" `ClientIDMode="Static"`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan because I have radioButtonList in toggle and if I don't use clientIDMde=static than toggle function doesn't works because ID gets modified when page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with your script.

You script is not being called after postback.

So use as below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // below will execute after ajax postback
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //script
    }

    // executes after page load first time

    //script

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ClientIDMode` of the RadioButtonList to `AutoID` (or not specify the attribute in the markup if that is the default value) and use a binding expression in client code to get the actual ID of the control:

```
$("#<%= areasList.ClientID %>")
```

or

```
document.getElementById('<%= areasList.ClientID %>')
```